# mujoco: Could not find GCC executable

Tags: python, macos, gcc, openai-gym, mujoco

I want to run `pip3 install -U 'mujoco-py<1.50.2,>=1.50.1'` on macOS but it returns

```
File "/private/var/folders/1t/t0dzx5fn3jn1r9lqx_2j3m9m0000gn/T/pip-install-i8wi8lki/mujoco-py_48d744c3b7c64c6abb74252cb291ab88/mujoco_py/builder.py", line 320, in _build_impl
      raise RuntimeError(
  RuntimeError: Could not find GCC executable.
  
  HINT: On OS X, install GCC with `brew install gcc`.
```

I have the following `gcc` version installed:

```
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

and am running Python version:

```
Python 3.9.17 (main, Jun 15 2023, 08:01:12) 
[Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
```

What is the problem here?

The ultimate goal is to install and run `gym[mujoco]==0.19`

I found [this](https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/issues/601) but it didn't help and concerns a different `mujoco` version.

Comment: Note that the default `gcc` is not actually GCC, it's the Apples Clang compiler installed using an alias. You could try to install the true GCC as instructed in the error message?

Comment: I have run `brew install gcc` as instructed and this is the output of `gcc -v` afterwards. How do I check if the true GCC is installed correctly?